# convert coordinates (x,y) to angle and create a rose diagram in r

Tags: r, package

I have a list of latitudes and longitudes which represent the mean center of accidents and hospital locations calculated using the gravity method, i.e for various accidents I have 1 mean latitude and longitude for year and 1 mean latitude and longitude for hospital. Now I want to create a rose diagram for both accident and hospital, calculate their correlation, significance, and direction of movement by year and mean direction as well, and other summary statistics using circular statistics. How do i proceed? Some ideas in R and R code would be helpful. I went through **circular** package, but I did not get how to convert the x, y coordinates into a single column to a create rose diagram and other analysis. Any help would be much appreciated.

My data is as follows: `LA` is longitude of Accidents, `LTA` is latitude of Accidents, `LH` is longitude of Hospitals, and `LTH` is longitude of hospitals.

```
df <- read.table(text='Year LA LTA LH LTH 
Year1 -84.3213 33.8488 -84.3281 33.8779 
Year2 -84.322 33.8470 -84.3284 33.8782 
year3 -84.323 33.84461 -84.3293 33.8791 
year4 -84.3165 33.8359 -84.3452 33.8404 
year5 -84.3257 33.8330 -84.3413 33.8340', header=TRUE)
```

These are the only data i have, so far, i converted that latitude and longitude into an Azimuth, which gave me an angle from origin i believe. Then i used that angle to draw rose diagram. I am not sure if i have to convert those negative coordinates to positive angle. Any inputs from statistics person would be appreciated. Since i have two angles from accidents and hospitals, i believe i can correlate and do watson test. following is my code so far and still working on it;The rose diagram is only for accidents not hospitals, is it good to draw both together? what other things can be done need ,ore suggestions please

```
library(geosphere)
library(circular)
library(CircStats)
data <- read.table("trial_circ.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
dfr<-data.frame(data[3:4])
dist<- trackAzimuth(as.matrix(dfr))
d<-rose.diag(dist)
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What would your desired output look like? Please edit an image or some data into your question.

Comment: These are the only data i have, so far, i converted that latitude and longitude into a n Azimuth, which gave me an angle from i origin i believe. Then i used that angle to draw rose diagram. I am not sure if i have to convert those negative coordinates to positive to make it spherical. Any inputs from statistics person would be appreciated. Since i have two angles from accidents and hospitals, i believe i can correlate and do watson test. My codes so far is below and still developing;